# Check ec2 exist with lambda boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, python-3.8

I have 1 list instance ID from s3 and i want to check each instance ID from s3 with instance ID from EC2 services for check ec2 exist. Could you help advise to me some solution ? Thanks

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
#Get all ec2 information - The current list in AWS
ins_inf = ec2_client.describe_instances()
for reservation in ins_inf['Reservations']:
    for ins_cur in reservation['Instances']:
        #Get all instance ID from ec2
        ins_cur_id = ins_cur["InstanceId"]
        #Get instance ID list from s3
        for ins_f_s3 in line_stream(s3_objload.get()['Body']):
            #Remove /n
            ins_f_s3_re=ins_f_s3.strip()
            #Compare instance ID from s3 with current instance ID in aws
            if ins_cur_id == ins_f_s3_re:
                print (ins_f_s3_re + ' found')
            else:
                print(ins_f_s3_re + ' not found in aws ')
```

And This is result

```
i-0a959c122fd51581e not found in aws
i-0a959c122fd51581f not found in aws 
i-0a959c122fd51581e found
i-0a959c122fd51581f not found in aws
```

Maybe you can see "i-0a959c122fd51581e" show 2 message when compare. It not correct. Can someone help me this case ? Thnk so much

Comment: You are printing `not found in aws` every time the current line from the file does not match. You want to print that only if its not found in any of the lines. I would also recommend loading the file into memory and not re-fetching the file from S3 for every instance in the reservations list.

Comment: Hi Jordanm, Thank your idea. Now my python already work well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-read your list of EC2 instances of interest from S3 and store them in a list. Then simply test each instance ID returned from the DescribeInstances call to see if it's in the S3 list (much as @jordanm suggests in the above comment).

```
s3_list = [x.strip() for x in line_stream(s3_objload.get()['Body'])]

ins_inf = ec2_client.describe_instances()

for reservation in ins_inf['Reservations']:
    for ins_cur in reservation['Instances']:

        # Get instance ID from ec2
        ins_cur_id = ins_cur["InstanceId"]
       
        if ins_cur_id in s3_list:
            print(ins_cur_id + ' found')
        else:
            print(ins_cur_id + ' not found')
```

Comment: Hi Jarmod, Thank for your advise. Now i can do it. Thnk so much